# How to set default color for column?

Tags: tabulator

Tabulator has builtin formatter [`color`](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/format#format-builtin)

Is there a way to set default column color (for all cells)?

something like:

```
columns: [
  { width: 50, color: "red" },
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no default way to do that built in to the formatter, but you could just use simple CSS to set the background color of cells in a column with a given field name

```
.tabulator .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell[tabulator-field="fieldname"]{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: This will change color of all cells, I need cells only at curtain column

Comment: example updated to include column specific highlighting